# git blame to get the commit history for all files in entire repo

Tags: git, csv, github

i am looking to get the commit history of every file in every folder under any repo. I am thinking to do brute force of `git blame` recursively and burn through all the folders, but how would i keep track of what file is under what folder, so yes the directory structure matters in this case as if i need to use the output of blame i would want to show what commit was made for what file under what folder. 
I would appreciate if i am shown the direction and how can i pipe all of this data into some csv file.
Secondly, is it possible to get the `blame` of all the branches not just the current one but in a separate csv file per branch ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Update: This is what i am doing right now;

```
for file in $(git ls-files); 
    do git blame $file;
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log): it can be applied to each file

```
git log -- afile
```

You can add `-M` in order to follow renames.

Comment: but i want something for per line commit of a file? like the output of git blame with porcelain.